# Logged In Username in Page Source

Tags: acumatica

is it possible to get logged in Username in page source, which we will further use is another application also what is the best approach to get the logged in username.

Answer (score 0):

By page source, do you mean a Graph/GraphExtension?

If so the logged in user information is already pre-fetch and easily accessible in PXGraph Accessinfo DataView. In a graph extension you would prefix the DataView with Base.

This example will display logged in username in the Traces window when opening SalesOrder screen:

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
  public override void Initialize()
  {
    PXTrace.WriteInformation(Base.Accessinfo.UserName);
  }
}
```